# Avoiding code duplication in react functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have n React functional components which share 90% of their content, but differ in a few functions they use.

Let's say my components are the following:

```
export default function BWPage(props) {
    const f = (x) => x+1
    const g = (x) => f(x)*2
    const h = (x) => g(x)*x
    return <div>{h(props.input)}</div>
}

export default function ColorPage(props) {
    const f = (x) => x+1
    const g = (x) => {props.setColor(f(x)); return 4;}
    const h = (x) => g(x)*x
    return <div>{h(props.input)}</div>
}
```

And so on. In OO programming I would obviously override the required function and be happy, but that isn't possible in React. The official guidelines say to use composition, but I don't see how that works here. Passing all functions that can be different as a prop is impractical as then `g` would be unable to call `f`. I also cannot create put all common functions somewhere else and import them, as then `h` isn't able to call `g`. What is the proper solution here?

Comment: Looks like you can easily abstract f and h into hook that accepts g as an argument, and in turn makes f and h available to g.

Comment: That does make sense! Would it be good practice to turn all the common logic into one hook?

Comment: Makes sense to me since they seem so closely related already.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! Also, any suggestions on what to do if I have k components with the same function f, and a few with a differing one? Should I make the hook have a default value for f (and any functions with similar problems)?

Comment: Sounds a viable solution. The hook needn't return a static result either, but could return a composed function (eg. h in your example)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code from the questions, there are a few points to note.

1. In both the components, the functions `f`, `g` and `h` are only used for calculating the value rendered inside the `div` element and nowhere else.

Since these functions look like pure functions (their return value only depends on their input params), you could move that logic outside to the parent component.

2. In the `g` method in the `ColorPage` component, `props.setColor` is called.

Assuming that this method updates the state in the parent component, it's not a good idea to do this. It might lead to infinite re-rendering. Better to cal it inside `useEffect` or some event handler.

Please check if the following implemention works for you

This is the parent component. Logic for calculating the rendered value inside `BWPage` and `ColorPage` is moved here.

```
export function MainContainerNew() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

  const f = x => x + 1;
  const gForBWPage = x => f(x) * 2;
  const gForColorPage = () => 4;
  const h = (x, cb) => cb(x) * x;

  if (condition1) {
    return <BWPage input={h(color, gForBWPage)} />;
  }

  if (condition2) {
    return <ColorPage input={h(color, gForColorPage)} setColor={setColor} />;
  }

  ... add all your other conditions here
}
```

You can add more types of the `g` method for different components using this approach.